# Visual Studio Report Designer shows only HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio, designer, report

I built a report in Visual Studio 2008. There was a problem with
it (an error occurred while trying to view the report) and since then, the
report designer shows just HTML,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
        .ErrorStyle { 
            font-family: tahoma; 
            font-size: 11 pt; 
            text-align: left
        }. etc. etc.
```

I can view the report in debug mode, but this doesn´t really help me.

How do I get the usual design view going again? Is this just broken? Has anyone had
this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the designer had some problems with a missing plug-in that was needed to display some data.

Comment: Considering I have the same problem, it would have been nice for you to clarify which plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

Check this line. Mine said Integrated, and I was getting the same results.

```
<rd:SecurityType>Windows</rd:SecurityType>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a workaround which works sometimes, but not a final solution:

Right click on the form file > View code, Then in the code panel, Right click > View Designer.

If you do this way it could sometimes work and show the form correctly.

Also, sometimes there is a missing/invalid reference causing the problem, in this case simply compile the project, and make sure that all references are valid.